# Firefox textarea sizing bug?

Tags: css, firefox, textarea, dimensions

I'm attempting to create a fixed textarea that fills the entire width and height of the browser window using just CSS, and the following works perfectly in Chrome:

```
textarea {
    border: 2px solid #3D6AA2;
    padding: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    resize: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BulletzBill/FZr9k/1/

However, if you view the fiddle in Firefox, it appears as though it does not take the `bottom` or `right` rules into account at all. Is this a known bug in firefox, or is there any workaround for it? I'd like to avoid using javascript/window resize listeners if possible.

Comment: Ok figured it out. Funny but this is proper behaviour and a Chrome works incorrectly in this case. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6815173/949476) and [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width).

Comment: hmm, interesting. I guess I am just so conditioned to treat webkit's implementation as gospel that I didn't even consider it was the one doing it wrong. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an update to your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZr9k/8/)

You need to make the `width:100%`, `height:100%` and `box-sizing: border-box;`

You only need 2 position points `top` and `left`

Comment: Problem with going that route is that then the textarea gets cut off, especially when you want to use padding/border on it. Look at this update to the fiddle to see what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/BulletzBill/FZr9k/6/. setting the top/right/bottom/left values all to zero works for other block-level elements such as `<div>`s in firefox, so thats why it just seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @BillDami Just use `box-sizing` http://jsfiddle.net/FZr9k/8/ However it's interesting why mozilla doe not stretch textarea.

Comment: It looks like that because the width is 100% + 4px as you have a 2px border on each side. just remove the border or if you need the border then you have to place it within another div

Comment: @Andrew yeah but I'd still want to have the padding on the textarea to keep the text from going right up against the scrollbar in chrome, and that adds to the height as well. Looks like `box-sizing` takes care of that though as dfsq suggested. If you can add that to your answer I'll mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: @BillDami I have updated my answer so that it goes to the most recent jsfiddle so it is easier for people to find and also mentioned `box-sizing`