# Display textarea size consistently in all Browsers

Tags: html, css

I've got a slight issue with the below code in IE.

The design is perfect in Chrome and Firefox but IE renders the *textarea* size very small. I want it as it looks in Firefox or Chrome.

It might be a duplicate of
[Consistently sizing a <textarea> under IE, FF, Safari/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038732/consistently-sizing-a-textarea-under-ie-ff-safari-chrome)
OR
[Firefox / IE textarea sizing quirk - workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906075/firefox-ie-textarea-sizing-quirk-workarounds)
but there are no proper solutions mentioned. So I started this.

I'm sure that jQuery can sort it out but I want only CSS in my page, Is there any proper **CSS** solution to it??

*I'm not able to log into jsFiddle, so, no jsFiddle guys..* :(

```
<!DOCROOT html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Code Compressor</title>

    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .column {
            width: 48%;
            margin: 1%;
            float: left;
        }

        textarea {
            min-width: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;

            min-height: 80%;
            max-height: 80%;

            overflow: auto;
        }

        .center {
            clear: both;
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>

</head>


<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="column">
            <div>Input Source:</div>
            <textarea id="sourceCode" name="sourceCode" ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div>Compressed Output:</div>
            <textarea id="outputCode" name="outputCode" ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="center">
            <input type="button" id="compressButton" name="compressButton" 
                value="Compress" onClick="compress" />
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what if you put `width: 100%; height: 80%` in your textarea's css?

Comment: @Aguardientico: The width works fine, but the Height is not increasing, It displays only 1 line by default now.

Comment: @GauthamPJ Your textarea is considering that the height of `.column` is just one line. Try to add to your `.column` a height of 300px, for example.

Comment: @chiefGui: Yeah, this increases the height, but displaces the *Compress Button* about an inch down the page.  :/

Comment: @PJ : Lo PJ, you don't need to login to Fiddle I say ! :-)

Comment: I just have this problem with Firefox. I think the row and col attribute of textarea behaves differently regards the browsers. I removed the row and col attribute and used width and height in my CSS. The problem is resolved in this way for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the height is not behaving as expected, so try to set a height for `.column`. Your `textarea` is inside of a column and its height is a percentage of his father, but, *how high is your father?*

### Updated

You told that the `.center` layer is overlapped by the columns if you set a height to the `textarea`, right? Then we must to set the columns relative to each other and we have to explain to HTML that our `.center` should to be after our columns. To do this, follow the code:

```
.column {
    width: 48%;
    height: 500px; /* for example */
    position: relative; /* add this to trasnform your columns 
                           relative to each other */
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
}

textarea {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;

    min-height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;

    overflow: auto;
}

.center {
    width: 100%; /* to specify that your "center" must 
                    to occupy 100% of the width on the screen. */
    position: relative; /* to transform the position to relative */
    float: left; /* to accompany the columns' floating */
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### Percentage comprehension

Just to make things look better for you: *to work with percentage, we **need** an initial point*. This means that for something to have 80% of the height of something else, we need to know the height of something else.

In other words, to `.something` have 80% of height, we need to know the height of his father, and if his father have 90% of height, the father of his father must to have a specified height. At some point, we need a defined height.

### JavaScript alternative

As I said, I have worked too much with percentage measures and no success to found a solution with pure CSS 2.1. Thereat, I created this *mini-plugin* in JavaScript + jQuery. No work-a-rounds:

```
function calculateResponsiveHeight(couple) {
    for (var value in couple) {
        $(value)
            .css("height", 
                 $(couple[value].wrapper).height() - 
                   couple[value].spacing + "px");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
calculateResponsiveHeight({
    ".content": {
        spacing: 135, // how much you want to spacing your layer?
        wrapper: window // who is the reference point?
    }
});
```

Comment: Did add the width and height, only the width is being affected, the height remains at only 1 line height.

Comment: Ok, if I give the height in PX, it'll work, but the Compress button does go a bit farther from the two textarea boxes. Can't I have *%* height so that it's totally dynamic??

Comment: You can define the height with percentage, but with pure CSS, at some point you'll need to have a defined height. With CSS 3, you can use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to make this completely dynamic, but without this function, you should use JavaScript.

Comment: Oh.. K.. This is the best answer up till now. For now I'll put in the PX value.. But will keep the thread open for a day to see if any new Answers turn up.

Comment: I'm working in an application that uses fully responsive layout and I'm working a lot with percentage. Seriously, I have searched too much around this subject and with pure CSS it is not possible. As I said, we need to know the height at some point.

Comment: Ok, accepted your answer, I guess there has to be a Starting point somewhere. But one last thing, how the heck does this work on other browsers properly..??? :-/

Comment: They are modern browsers with the power to calculate the height dynamically by itself.

Comment: K.. Fair enough.. Thanks for clearing this doubt for me **chiefGui**.. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#outputCode{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: if it is inside a div than 100% height means height of the parent div...instead of 100% use a static height like 250px it also not effect responsive css beacuse vertical scroll is allowed in responsive css...so try with a fixed height

Comment: Yeah, did try that, it's working, but I wanted it in **%** so that it displays to a certain height of the page. Is it possible?

Comment: if you want to display height of textarea it's parent tag will be body or a div whose height will be 100%... when ever we give css in % it initiate from its parent element

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared a height, add in a "height: 80%", you have just said what the max can be and the min can be - it doesn't intrinsically know what it should be in between.

Comment: seems to work okay for me, what version of IE are you testing in? Could always try declaring html, body and container with a height of 100%?

Comment: I'm using IE9, have added **height: 90%** in **textarea**, still no difference. Only 1 line of Text Area is being displayed.